# Counting data based on decades

Tags: mysql

I have a table `Books` with a column for the release year of a book (type: year). I want to count the number of books released in every decade.

I have tried the following:

```
select count(*) as count, concat(decade, '-', decade + 9) as ReleaseYear
from (
    select floor('ReleaseYear' / 10) * 10 as decade
    from Book
) t
group by decade;
```

But it is returns 0 results.

When I try `year('ReleaseYear')` it returns nulls.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `decade` value for each row and find the count(decade) .. group by decade.

**Query**

```
select t.decade,count(t.decade) as BooksCount from
(
    select *,
    concat((releaseYear - ((releaseYear % 10)-1)),'-',((releaseYear - ((releaseYear % 10)-1))+ 9)) as decade
   from Books
)t
group by t.decade;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b37e/9)

Comment: The above query should work as you told like `releaseYear` column having the datatype `year`. Please provide some sample data or create a sample fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
SELECT 
    count(*) `count`,
    concat(FLOOR(year(`ReleaseYear`)/10)*10, '-', FLOOR(year(`ReleaseYear`)/10)*10  +  9) `ReleaseYear`
from `books`
group by FLOOR(year(`ReleaseYear`)/10)*10
```

**Demo** [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/953a6/4)

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your table structure.